# edit Xml File using C#

Tags: c#

this is my xml file...

-->

```
<!--Daily Genarated File Path-->
<add key="DailyFilName" value="C:\DailySummary.xls"/>
<!--Weekly Genarated File Path-->
<add key="WeeklyFilName" value="C:\WeeklySummary.xls"/>
<!--Log File Path-->
<add key="LogFilName" value="c:\\TranmittalsLog.txt"/>
```

i need to edit my DailyFilName by c#. Using Key i need to change the value.

Comment: is this App.config file?

Answer (score 3):

Well depending on the type of File there are a number of options you can use.

If it is a standard XML file then there are built in .NET classes you can use such as [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) and [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx). Examples avaliable on MSDN.

If it is an app.config file then you can use the Configuration namespace to work directly with the file without the need to read/write the Xml manually. Check out the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class on MSDN for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

[NOTE: if you are trying to manipulate appSettings section in app.config or web.config file, use of [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) is recommended.]

You can do something like this :

```
    private void SetValue(String key, String value)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("...");
        XElement element = doc.Descendants("add").Where(d => d.Attribute("key") != null && d.Attribute("key").Value == key).First();
        element.Attribute("value").Value = value;
    }
```

Usage

```
SetValue("DailyFilName", "...");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this if you are working with a app.config file

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "C:\\App.config"};

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["SettingKey1"].Value = "newValue";
config.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SetValue(string xmlFilePath, string key, string value)
{
   try
   {
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
      XElement element = doc.Descendants("add").Where(d => d.Attribute("key") != null && d.Attribute("key").Value == key).First();
      element.Attribute("value").Value = value;
      doc.Save(xmlFilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```