# How to change update the element value in XML with C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file and wanted to update and save the value of target load with C# code. My code is as below which is trying to xml shown below -

```
var fileName = textBox1.Text;
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
            xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("factoryTest/targetLoad").InnerText = "80";
            xmlDoc.Save(fileName);




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<factoryTest xmlns="urn:gcpm">
  <targetLoad>90</targetLoad>
  <isAccepted>true</isAccepted>
  <isCertified>true</isCertified>
  <isAtRatingConditions>true</isAtRatingConditions>
  <supervisorName>Eric Larson</supervisorName>
</factoryTest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [edit Xml File using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254307/edit-xml-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Somnath Please go thru the question mentioned in the comment above and try to solve your issue using that approach. If you face any issue in that, you can post it here.

Comment: I have already tried several options but none was helping my scenario.

var fileName = textBox1.Text;
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
                xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("factoryTest/targetLoad").InnerText = "80";
                xmlDoc.Save(fileName);

Comment: @Somnath you can edit your question with that code and provide details about what is not working.

Comment: I have a xml file whose content needs to be updated and saved with the help of C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(tFileName);
            xdoc.Elements("{urn:gcpm}factoryTest").Elements("{urn:gcpm}targetLoad").FirstOrDefault().Value = textBox2.Text;
            xdoc.Save(tFileName);
```